# Access a class's fields and methods to retrieve a field with some value

Tags: java

I'm trying to access a document class that has id, name, text and list of words. I try to compare a document id which I have with the ids and when found get the list of words attached to this id to find exact word and return its frequency.
Any help is highly appreciated.

```
public class Doc {
    private int documentID;
    private static Doc docInstance = null;
    private String documentText;
    private ArrayList<String> listOfTokens;
    static int docCount = 0;
    int tokFreq = 0;

    public Doc() {
        documentID = 0;
        listOfTokens = new ArrayList<String>();
        tokFreq = 0;
        docCount++;
    }

    public static Doc getDocInstance() { 
        if (docInstance == null) {
            docInstance = new Doc();
        }
        return docInstance;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getListOfTokens() { 
        return listOfTokens;
    }

    public void setDocumentID(int x){ 
        if (getDocumentID() != x)
           this.documentID = x;
    }
}
```

and I am trying this

```
public static void createDocumentVector(TreeMap<Integer,Integer> 
documentVector, TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>qm, int N) 
{
    int eachDoc = 0;

    Collection<String> allKeys = qm.keySet();
    ArrayList<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    boolean addedTerm = false;

    /**
    Obtain an Iterator for Collection
    */
    Iterator<String> itr = allKeys.iterator();
    String key;
    int termFrequency = 0;
    int documentFrequency = 0;

    /**
     Iterate through TreeMap values iterator
     */
    while(itr.hasNext()) 
    {
        key = (String)itr.next();
        Integer LL = 0;
        l1 = qm.get(key); // Returns value of that key
        for (int k = 0; k < l1.size(); k++) 
        {
            LL = l1.get(k);
            Doc doc = new Doc();
            doc.getDocInstance().setDocumentID(LL);
            int size = doc.getListOfTokens().size();
            String[] docIdTokens =  doc.getListOfTokens().toArray(new String[size]);
            for (String s : docIdTokens){
              if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(key)){
                 termFrequency++;
              }
            }

            documentFrequency = l1.size();
            eachDoc = getTFIDF(termFrequency, documentFrequency, N);
            documentVector.put(eachDoc, LL);
        }


    }
}
```

It doesn't run completely and gives source not found, in debugging.
I am thinking to change class Doc into this:

```
public class Doc<ListOfTokens> {

private static int documentID;
private static Doc docInstance = null;
private String documentName;
private String documentText;
private HashMap<String, Integer> ListOfTokens = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
private TreeMap<Integer, ListOfTokens> documentMap = new TreeMap<Integer, ListOfTokens>();
int tokFreq = 0;
static int docCount = 0;
-----
}
```

but this would be a bit complicated I think. So any suggestions would be a great help.

Comment: Look, you do not want to use `static` - this means that there will be only one of these Objects.  In your code only one `documentID`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the keyword `static` for the documentID property of class Doc. Since you are expecting that there will be multiple doc objects and each needs to have their own value for documentID, you need to use documentID as a non-static field.

Comment: thanks for the note, i changed it, but any more ideas!plz